# Definition of $f \vee g$ and $f \wedge g$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In Olav Kallenberg's *Foundations of Modern Probability* he uses the notation $f \vee g$ and $f \wedge g$ where $f, g$ are two functions from a set $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. What does this notation mean?

Comment: The only other use of $\land$ and $\lor$ (apart from Cameron's answer) I've seen are $\land = min$ and $\lor = max$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, we have $$(f\vee g)(x)=\max\bigl(f(x),g(x)\bigr)$$ and $$(f\wedge g)(x)=\min\bigl(f(x),g(x)\bigr).$$

This accords with a typical notion in boolean algebras that is often generalized to partially ordered sets, where $a\vee b$ and $a\wedge b$ indicate (respectively) the least upper bound and greatest lower bound of $a,b.$

Answer (score 2):

These are just the pointwise max and min of $f$ and $g$, respectively.  That is, $$(f\vee g)(x)=\max(f(x),g(x))$$ and $$(f\wedge g)(x)=\min(f(x),g(x)).$$  More generally, if $f$ and $g$ are elements of a poset, $f\vee g$ refers to the least upper bound of $f$ and $g$ and $f\wedge g$ refers to the greatest lower bound of $f$ and $g$ (if such elements exist).  In this case, the poset is the set of all functions $\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, ordered by $f\leq g$ iff $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x$.