# What does $\wedge$, $\vee$ and $\triangle$ mean in real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

The context where I found them is the following.

> For a measurable space $(X,M)$ and $f, g : X → \mathbb{R}, a \in \mathbb{R}$ then $a · f, f + g$,
>   and $f · g$ are all measurable.
>   Moreover, if $f, g : X → \mathbb{R}$ then $f ∧ g$ and $f ∨ g$ are measurable, as is $|f|$.

and

> $57$ (metric on $L_C(M)$) Let $(X,M, µ)$ be a finite metric space (ie. $µ(X) < ∞$). Define $d$
>   on $L_C(M)$ via $d(f, g) = \int
> |f − g| ∧ 1dµ = d(f − g, 0)$.

for $\triangle$ (in the last sentence),

> $62$ (Approximation properties of $m^n$
>   ) We let $m^n$ be the completion of $m × · · · × m$
>   where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. So $L^
> n$
>   is the Lebesgue measurable sets on $\mathbb{R}^
> n$
>   .
>   Take $E ∈ L^n$
>   . Then
>
> 1. $m^n
>    (E) = \inf\{m^n
>    (O) | E ⊆ O$ and $O$ is open$\}
>    = \sup\{m^n
>    (K) | K ⊆ E$ and $K$ is compact$\}$.
> 2. $E = A_1\setminus N_1$ where $A_1$ is $G_δ$ and $m^n
>    (N_1) = 0$,
>      $E = A_2 ∪ N_2$ where $A_2$ is $F_σ$ and $m^n
>    (N_2) = 0$
> 3. $m^n
>    (E) < ∞$ implies $∀\epsilon > 0, ∃(R_j )
>    ^N
>    _{j=1}$ of disjoint open rectangles such that $m^n
>    (E \triangle
>    (∪R_j )) = 0$

Seems $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are used between functions, and it looks the wedge product of differential forms in the second paragraph, not sure if it is since this is the real analysis class and we didn't cover any of differential geometry.

And $\triangle$ seems to be used between sets and I think it is the same as the set minus operator '$\setminus$', I don't know why the $\epsilon$ comes up and guess it is related to $\triangle$ somehow?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

- $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are $\min$ and $\max$, respectively. (See, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415406/definition-of-f-vee-g-and-f-wedge-g).)
- $\Delta$ is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference): $A\Delta B = (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$.